# Handling JavaScript null string concatenation

Tags: javascript

Why is it in JavaScript that `null+'' === 'null'` ?

At least this is the case on Chrome 68.

It doesn't make a sense to me. Different languages handle it differently of course, but I would assume either `null` or `''` to be a better answer.

It just makes it hard to check if something is 'null' or if it is `null + ''`. Which could happen in a text field for example.

This is particularly an issue with ECMAScript 6 where you can do

```
value={\`${value}`}
```

etc.

Comment: To answer in simple language, `+` operator does 2 things, add or concat. if one of value is not getting converted to int, it converts both values to string using internal string function. For sample you can try `String(null);` This returns you `"null"` and hence it is equal. Hope that addresses your query

Answer (score 0):

By doing `console.log(null+'')` which is adding an empty string to `null`, you are just converting `null` to a string.

Look at some of the examples below:

```js
var first = 100 + '';
var second = 10 + '' + 2;
var third = undefined + '';
var fourth = null + '';

console.log(typeof first);
console.log(typeof second);
console.log(typeof third);
console.log(typeof fourth);
```